# Access to variable in strange piece of code

Tags: java, android

I have one strange piece of code here. I also can't name it, cause it's misunderstood by myself.

```
String [] x = new String[1];

someWorkableMethod(new CoolClass()
{
    @Override
    public void Something(String s) {
    x[0] = s;
}
});
```

p.s. there are no syntax errors, anyway, they do not matter
So, actually variable s is not null (Log.d returned normal result), but when I try to Log.d (x[0]) it returns Exception, that says that x[0] is null.
How to write s value to x[0] in the Something()? Thanx for help! )

Full code, if needed.

```
    public class Connection { 

private String key = "SMTH"; 
private static final String BASE_URL = "SMTH"; 
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(); 

private String post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler Handler) { 
client.post(url, params, Handler); 
//client. 
return ""; 
} 

public String createAuth(String login, String password, String device) { 
RequestParams params = new RequestParams(); 
params.put("login", login); 
params.put("password", password); 
params.put("device", device); 
params.put("key", this.key); 
params.put("method", "createAuth"); 
final String[] res = new String[1]; 
post(BASE_URL, params, new TextHttpResponseHandler(){ 

@Override 
public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBytes, Throwable throwable) { 
super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseBytes, throwable); 
} 

@Override 
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBytes) { 
super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, responseBytes); 
} 

@Override 
public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, String s, Throwable throwable) { 

} 

@Override 
public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, String s) { 
Log.d("LoginActivity", s); 
res[0] = s.toString(); 
} 
}); 
// Log.d("LoginActivity", res[0]); 
return res[0]; 
} 
}
```

Comment: I mean, i can't access x variable in Something(). I need to get access. For example, in class we can get something by this.something. I am looking for solution similar to that.

Comment: can you post body of `someWorkableMethod()`?

Comment: Sasha, have a look at edited version of question. Thanks for support

Comment: this is very likely to happen because you try to print returned `x[0]` immediately--before `onSuccess()` is invoked in callback.

Comment: yep, indeed, that's the problem. See edit in @Sourabh answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a workaround for accessing/changing variables from anonymous inner classes. You can change

```
String [] x = new String[1];
```

to

```
final String [] x = new String[1];
```

and this should make it accessible. I personally don't like this method, there are better ways to set values from inside anonymous functions.

Also, be cautious when using anonymous inner classes, if they last longer than your activity's life cycle, it might cause an activity leak

**EDIT**

```
// Log.d("LoginActivity", res[0]);
return res[0];
```

You are returning/logging value of `res[0]` before it is assigned. `success()` is not called till the http requests completes but the above 2 lines are called before that and this `res[0]` is null

Comment: thank you, but i have already added final String [] x = new String[1]; it's my fault, that i forgot to apply it to question. final is already used.

Comment: Thank you for answer, you are completely right! Could you say how can i avoid this mistake with time? )

Comment: See my previous comment

Comment: A proper answer to that will require more information but I guess you can add instance of `TextHttpResponseHandler` in `createAuth()` arguments and use it inside `post()`. This way the calling function will tell the `createAuth()` what to do with the response/error.

Answer (score 0):

The `x[0]` in the newly declared `CoolClass` is not in the same scope. This may be easier to conceptualize if you imagine that the CoolClass declaration is in it's own file.

Something like this may work if you also pass in the `x` string array.

```
String [] x = new String[1];

someWorkableMethod(new CoolClass()
{
    @Override
    public void Something(String[] x, String s) {
    x[0] = s;
}
});
```

Comment: *'The x[0] in the newly declared CoolClass is not in the same scope'*--yes, but it is visible in nested scope unless not re-defined

Comment: Deal is in one thing. CoolClass is system class and I can't change its methods arguments and another parameters. Have a look at full source question

Comment: @MrGeorgeous `post(...)` is a common method with self-explaining name familiar to developers. No need to obfuscate it behind `someMethod()` or whatever.

Comment: After seeing the full code, I should have know you would not likely be able to change the arguments to the overridden method. You should see if the other solution regarding lifecycle solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to turn async `createAuth()` into sync using some sinchronization technique, e. g. [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html):

```
public String createAuth(String login, String password, String device) { 
    //...
    final String[] res = new String[1]; 
    final Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0);
    post(BASE_URL, params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() { 
        // ...

        @Override 
        public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, String s) { 
            Log.d("LoginActivity", s); 
            res[0] = s.toString(); 
            s.release();    // release a permit
        } 
    }); 

    s.acquire();            // block until permit is available
    Log.d("LoginActivity", res[0]); 
    return res[0]; 
}
```

Thus, execution of `createAuth()` is blocked until semaphore permit is released in `onSuccess()`. After that `res[0]` is guaranteed to be set and can be read safely (unless other callback method triggered -- certainly, you need to put `s.release()` there also).

As this solution locks the thread it is executed in, it is strongly discouraged to run this in UI thread.